# Use 4TB partition with old NTFS-3G which doesn't support GPT and RAID

Tags: partitioning, raid, ntfs, mbr, ntfs-3g

I've a [D-Link Router (2750U)](http://www.dlinkmea.com/site/index.php/site/productDetails/232) which has a USB port and FTP Server. I've also a 4TB External H.D.D which I want to use as one partition with this Router as my home cloud. I don't want to split this H.D.D to more than one partition.

I've tried to mount this H.D.D to the Router but I discovered that ntfs-3g is very old version which doesn't support GPT (2009.4.4) so I should use MBR partition table.

I tried to make RAID 0 between two partitions (1.8 TB each) and formatted them as NTFS but ntfs-3g couldn't mount them with the following error:

```
~ $ ntfs-3g /dev/usb/sd/sda1 /mnt
Failed to read last sector (486399999): Invalid argument
HINTS: Either the volume is a RAID/LDM but it wasn't setup yet,
    or it was not setup correctly (e.g. by not using mdadm --build ...),
    or a wrong device is tried to be mounted,
    or the partition table is corrupt (partition is smaller than NTFS),
    or the NTFS boot sector is corrupt (NTFS size is not valid).
Failed to mount '/dev/usb/sd/sda1': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/usb/sd/sda1' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

Though this partition is mounted correctly on my Laptop in each case (GPT, RAID0 or even MBR with 4TB partition).

So what do you think is the solution here? I've heard about some quirky methods to support GPT and MBR at the same time, or to add support for more 4TB in MBR. What do you know about that?

Comment: Unless you can place new firmware on the router which uses an update version of the NTFS-3G driver you are sort of out of luck.  Its not clear the reason you think you need GPT though.

Comment: There's no firmware newer that I've. and though it's compiled in 2013 but they use very old version of ntfs-3g from 2009!

I need GPT to support 4TB partition because MBR doesn't support more than 2.2 TB partition size. and I don't want to split the H.D.D to more than one partition.

Comment: There are [third-party firmwares](http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/d-link/dsl-2650u) for hundreds of different routers.  I was suggesting you use one of those.  If you are not willing to use multiple partitions and you cannot use one of those alternate firmwares then you are out of luck.

Comment: Thanks Ramhound, I'm sorry as I thought about the customized firmware before but I didn't found my Router supported by anything. I think I'm gonna buy a Raspberry Pi and install my ownCloud server connected with my external H.D.D.